# Print files that are created in exact given date python

Tags: python, datetime

So i have this code and I want to copy files that are created in only in "2022.02.01"

```
import os, glob, shutil, datetime

target_dir=/home/blabla

for source_dir in glob.iglob("/mnt/bla/bla/bla*/*bla*/bla/bla/*.bla.png"
 d = "*.bla.png".datetime("2022,02,01")
if source_dir == d
   shutil.copy(source_dir, target_dir)
```

but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "s.py", line 33, in <module>
  d= "*.bla.png".datetime("2022,02,01")
AtributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Any suggestions how to fix that?
It works fine until i add the date I want this script to print my files to my given direction

Comment: To confirm, you have files with a date in them and some other text and you want to copy only the ones with a specific date?

Comment: @atru To only copy the ones with a specific date

Comment: And the format of the date in the name of those files is always the same? YYYY.MM.DD?

Comment: @atru Yep, they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `datetime` module to make it work. Since all the dates have the same format, you can identify the files to copy with a simple string check,

```
import glob, shutil

target_dir='test'
target_date = '2022.02.01'

for source_dir in glob.iglob("bla*.txt"):
    if target_date in source_dir:
        shutil.copy(source_dir, target_dir)
```